# Where can I listen to authentic Fado in Lisbon?

Tags: portugal, music, lisbon

I am looking for a nice place to listen to fado in Lisbon.
Unfortunatly there are too many tourist oriented venues. 
Not that Fado is bad there, but you're certainly going to pay tourist prices and, worst of all, you may not feel the real atmosphere with locals. Fado needs a special mood.

It's not a requirement at all but if anyone knows a nice place for "bummer" fado that would be great.

[image: Fado painting]

Comment: Did you find a good place? Please tell us...
It would also be nice if you chose the best answer.

Answer (score 8):

This is a big problem. To find a place is [easy](http://www.portaldofado.net/). Of course all these places are for tourists. They have a web site, advertising and everything.

A really nice place to see traditional fado is a place where you feel like you are in 1970.

I recommend the [Tasca do Chico](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Restaurant_Review-g189158-d2217877-Reviews-A_Tasca_do_Chico-Lisbon_Estremadura.html) it is a traditional place where I used to bring my parents and friends when I lived in Portugal.

Another great place to go to find great Fado is Bairro Alto. Walk around the streets and check inside the small doors to try to find traditional Fado. Usually the ***tascas*** have a different atmosphere. You can experience a real Portuguese night.

Fado has some rules. In a place to listen Fado you must be quiet, noise and conversation must be avoided in this place. At the end of the music you must hit the glasses (like in the cheers) instead of clapping.

Comment: I recommend clapping instead of clinking with glass. Some fado houses and concert halls also do fado shows without dinner. they usually offer daily shows.

Answer (score 4):

I recomend you to discover this section of the Fado Museum's website: http://roteiro.museudofado.pt/.
You can find there the traditional districts and houses with information about each place.

You are right about being cautious with "tourist" prices. About the mood, in my opinion the average quality of most houses is high, I believe you'll find a good atmosphere and enjoy the Fado.

Answer (score 1):

A Viela in the Alfama section of town, small and not full tourist...